# Updating table where LIKE has several criteria

Tags: sql, string, postgresql-9.3

I have two tables in PostgreSQL (version 9.3).  The first holds id, title and the second holds schdname.  I'm trying to create a select statement that will retrieve id and title where the title contains the schdname from the other table. The id, title table can hold several thousand rows.  I can do this fine if I use WHERE LIKE for an individual schdname example but there are 40 plus names so this is not practical.

My original query ran like this which I know doesn't work but would show what I'm trying to achieve.

SELECT
    id,
    title,
    dname
FROM
    mytable

WHERE
    title LIKE (
        SELECT
            schdname
        FROM
            schedule
        )

This produces an error of more than one row returned by the subquery used as an expresssion.  So my question is can this be achieved another way?

Comment: Looks like you want the IN operator, although, it's suitable for exact searches, not approximate ones (in case you want to use wildcards)

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do that:

```
SELECT id, title, dname FROM mutable
JOIN schedule ON mutable.title like '%' || schedule.schdname || '%'
```

Or a sligtly more readable way:

```
SELECT id, title, dname FROM mutable
JOIN schedule ON POSITION(schedule.schdname in mutable.title)<>0
```

Comment: Many thanks for this solution which works fine.  Second issue is that it works too well!  It's picking up parts of words in the schdname that is wrong.  As an example when looking for instances of the schdname 'AJE' it also returns data for the title 'VIAJE'.  The search needs to be on whole words within join so not sure if IN is going to work in this case.  Any suggestions?

Comment: If you need whole word matches, why do you use `LIKE`? Just use `=`

Answer (score 0):

Are you actually using a wildcard with like? You don't say so above. If not you can replace like with IN. If you do want to do a wildcard join I'd recommend taking a substring of the columns and comparing that e.g.

### names

james
jack
janice

select substr(names,1,2) as names_abbr
from names_table where names_abbr = (select ...)